# Here maps javascript api throws error in Internet explorer 11 while it opens fine in chrome.

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am trying to create a web page for here maps using its javascript api. It opens fine in google chrome but gives error in internet explorer.
The error in IE is "TypeError: Unable to get property 'mapsjs-core' of undefined or null reference".  I am using IE 11.

The html has few methods to initiliase the map and place the marker.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>"Show up"</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MapContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 92%; position: absolute; overflow: visible;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var marker;
        var position;
        var map;
        var mapEvents;
        var behavior;
        var ui1;


        function placeMarker(latitude, longitude) {
            try {

                var mlat = latitude;

                   if (marker) {
                        //Remove previous marker to add new marker
                        map.removeObject(marker);

                        //remove infobubbles
                        var previousBubbles = ui1.getBubbles();
                        previousBubbles.forEach(function (bubs) {
                            ui1.removeBubble(bubs);
                        });
                    }

                    chosen_location = { lng: longitude, lat: latitude };
                    marker = new H.map.Marker(chosen_location);
                    map.addObject(marker);

                    var infowindow = new H.ui.InfoBubble({ lng: longitude, lat: latitude }, { content: 'Latitude: ' + latitude + '<br>Longitude: ' + longitude });
                    ui1.addBubble(infowindow);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert("Exception in placeMarker");
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        function initialize() {
        try{

            var platform = new H.service.Platform({ app_id: '{app id}', app_code: '{app code}', useCIT: true, useHTTPS: true });
            var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
            defaultLayers.normal.map.setMin(3);
            defaultLayers.normal.map.setMax(10);

            // initialize a map - this map is centered over {0.0}
            var mapContainer = document.getElementById("MapContainer");
            map = new H.Map(mapContainer, defaultLayers.normal.map);

            // MapEvents enables the event system
            mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

            // Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object: 
            behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

            // Create the default UI components
            ui1 = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

            //Managing the Position of UI Controls
            var mapSettings = ui1.getControl('mapsettings');
            var zoom = ui1.getControl('zoom');
            var scalebar = ui1.getControl('scalebar');

            mapSettings.setAlignment('top-left');
            zoom.setAlignment('top-left');
            scalebar.setAlignment('top-left');

            map.addEventListener('tap', function (evt) {
                var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX, evt.currentPointer.viewportY);
                placeMarker(Math.abs(coord.lat.toFixed(4)), Math.abs(coord.lng.toFixed(4)));
            });
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
            }

        }

        window.addEventListener('load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a local file or behind a web server ? IE 11 has some security checks which might block requests in a local file.

Comment: It is a local file.

Comment: Local file will not work with Javascript API + IE 11,  kindly try putting the file behind a web server.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any specific reason why it would not work?

Comment: Sorry, @HEREDeveloperSupport not sure I really understand what you're suggesting. Can you point me in the right direction for solving this? I'm getting an error related to map js core only one IE 11 as well: `Unable to get property 'cancel' of undefined or null reference` via /v3/3.1/mapsjs-core.js in Q.prototype.reload at line 264:219

Comment: I'm also seeing this error on Edge 17.17134 and Edge 18.18362 @HEREDeveloperSupport. It seems like we'd want to use the legacy mapjs as well. Not sure if that's related to the issue

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport sorry can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: @JackHoward, this example on https://jsfiddle.net/yxet9mh5/1/ should work for IE17/18 in legacy mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you have IE11 under Windows 7 be sure that you have a last update for IE11:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45134 (32 bit）

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45154 (64 bit）

Set into head tag follow:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
</head>
```

This code works for me without any errors in IE11 for Win 7 and Win 10:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>

<head>
    <title>"Show up"</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="https://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-mapevents.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="MapContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 92%; position: absolute; overflow: visible;">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var marker;
        var position;
        var map;
        var mapEvents;
        var behavior;
        var ui1;


        function placeMarker(latitude, longitude) {
            try {

                var mlat = latitude;

                if (marker) {
                    //Remove previous marker to add new marker
                    map.removeObject(marker);

                    //remove infobubbles
                    var previousBubbles = ui1.getBubbles();
                    previousBubbles.forEach(function(bubs) {
                        ui1.removeBubble(bubs);
                    });
                }

                chosen_location = {
                    lng: longitude,
                    lat: latitude
                };
                marker = new H.map.Marker(chosen_location);
                map.addObject(marker);

                var infowindow = new H.ui.InfoBubble({
                    lng: longitude,
                    lat: latitude
                }, {
                    content: 'Latitude: ' + latitude + '<br>Longitude: ' + longitude
                });
                ui1.addBubble(infowindow);
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Exception in placeMarker");
                alert(e);
            }
        }

        function initialize() {
            try {

                var platform = new H.service.Platform({
                    app_id: 'YOUR_APP_ID',
                    app_code: 'YOU_APP_CODE',
                    useCIT: true,
                    useHTTPS: true
                });
                var defaultLayers = platform.createDefaultLayers();
                defaultLayers.normal.map.setMin(3);
                defaultLayers.normal.map.setMax(10);

                // initialize a map - this map is centered over {0.0}
                var mapContainer = document.getElementById("MapContainer");
                map = new H.Map(mapContainer, defaultLayers.normal.map);

                // MapEvents enables the event system
                mapEvents = new H.mapevents.MapEvents(map);

                // Instantiate the default behavior, providing the mapEvents object: 
                behavior = new H.mapevents.Behavior(mapEvents);

                // Create the default UI components
                ui1 = H.ui.UI.createDefault(map, defaultLayers);

                //Managing the Position of UI Controls
                var mapSettings = ui1.getControl('mapsettings');
                var zoom = ui1.getControl('zoom');
                var scalebar = ui1.getControl('scalebar');

                mapSettings.setAlignment('top-left');
                zoom.setAlignment('top-left');
                scalebar.setAlignment('top-left');

                map.addEventListener('tap', function(evt) {
                    var coord = map.screenToGeo(evt.currentPointer.viewportX, evt.currentPointer.viewportY);
                    placeMarker(Math.abs(coord.lat.toFixed(4)), Math.abs(coord.lng.toFixed(4)));
                });
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }

        }

        window.addEventListener('load', initialize);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```